# How to sent argument to handler event in React render component not using lambda function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lambda, arrow-functions

I have React app and i know it is not a good to way use lambda function in the property of a render component, because it is reduces application performance like this:

```
       <ConfirmSmsModal
          modal={args.modal}
          smsCheck={async (code: string) => {
            return await this._vm.onPressCodeConfirmSave(code);
          }}
          cancel={this._vm.onPressCancel}
        />
```

And it is a good way to put just an event handler instead of lambda function. But how can i do it if i need to get a parameter from the smsCheck property, like code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using lambdas (arrow functions) inside your handlers to receive aditional parameters besides the fact that it breaks memoization. You can always create a custom function to deal with the operation an pass a reference to your handler `smsCheck={handleSmsCheck}`

Comment: Do you mean like this? private async _smsCheck(code: string) { return await this._vm.onPressCodeConfirmSave(code); } and i will note lose an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with declaring anonymous functions directly inside `render` is that it breaks `memoization` since a new function is created on each render the shallow comparison of `Object.is` will always asserts to `false`.

There is nothing wrong with your code but you can always decouple your logic from `render` by lifting it to a handler

```
class Component extends React.Component{
    async handleOperation = param =>{
        const result = await apiCall(param)
    }

    render(){
        return <Child callback={this.handleOperation} />
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
smsCheck={someFunction.bind(this, paramYouWantToSend)}
```